# SqlDataReader не видит передаваемые параметры

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

Сам Sql запрос работает 100%, но как передать параметр в него чтобы это видел `SqlDataReader`. Сейчас он видит, что `HasRow` ничего нет.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.ConnectionString))
{
    // SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("@id_trans", idTrans);

    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SelectNaklInGroupNakl, connection);
    //  command.Parameters.Add("@id_trans", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = idTrans;
    var param = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@id_trans";
    param.Value = "Value";
    command.Parameters.Add(param);
    //  SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("@id_trans", idTrans);

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows) // если есть данные
    {
        while (reader.Read()) // построчно считываем данные
        {
            string ert = reader.GetValue(0).ToString() ?? "";
        }
    }
}
```

С простым Sql запросом не работает и все.

```
string selectNaklInGroupNakl = @"select * from tov_doc where id_trans = ' @id_trans ' ";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.ConnectionString))
{
    // SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("@id_trans", idTrans);

    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectNaklInGroupNakl, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_trans", idTrans);

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read()) // построчно считываем данные
    {
        string ert = reader.GetValue(0).ToString() ?? "";
    }                
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у Вас HasRow является лишней проверкой.  while (reader.Read()) - достатточно, вход в цикл не произойдёт, если ридер ничегоне "зацепил" из базы :-)

Comment: Проверка лишняя, но проблема то в другом. Ридер не цепляет параметры запроса.

Comment: `@"select * from tov_doc where id_trans = ' @id_trans ' ";` - попробуйте убрать первый символ `@` и одинарные кавычки.

Comment: Это были кавычки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в следующем. При выполнении запроса к Б.Д. необходимы было указывать '' для корректного ввода значения, либо выпадало в ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С кавычками всё ок в базе, соответственно я подумал что в программе нужно тоже заключить передаваемый параметр в ''

Но оказалось что так оно не работает. Убрав кавычки всё благополучно заработало.
Остается только один вопрос. Как он сам это определил и как это внутри отработало?
[image]

Comment: Параметр не является частью текста sql-запроса. Параметры передаются отдельно, в специальной области памяти. При этом они имеют тип. Парсер sql всё это учитывает и подставляет значение параметра в уже разобранный запрос как единое целое.

Comment: Если интересно внутреннее устройство параметров, могу посоветовать книгу Mastering SQL, Martin Gruber (2000). Есть в русском переводе от издательства "Лори" (2003). Не путать с книгой "Понимание SQL" того же автора! Искать в книгах термин descriptor (дескриптор), глава 22.

Answer (score 0):

А если так?

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.ConnectionString)) {
            // SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("@id_trans", idTrans);

            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SelectNaklInGroupNakl, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_trans", idTrans);

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read()) // построчно считываем данные
            {

                string ert = reader.GetValue(0).ToString() ?? "";

            }
        }
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло.

Comment: зогадка... прямо промоделировать хочется!

Comment: я у себя проверил с простой таблицей - работает. У Вас на картинке виден кусочек SQL запроса. Попробуйте в селекте вместо звёздочки написать перечисление полей. Еще - есть подозрение, что с ридером работать через GetValue() не очень хорошо, лучше сразу спрашивать у поля значение определенного типа reader.GetString(1), например